# how to setImageMatrix an edittext (convert it to imageview first)

Tags: android, bitmap, drag-and-drop, android-edittext, imageview

I want to create an edittext that can be drag-drop, rotate and resize. I found [this](https://github.com/Almeros/android-gesture-detectors) library on github and want to use it.

The library working fine in imageview but i cant use it directly on the edittext because edittext dont have `setImageMatrix` method.

So my goal is to convert the edittext to the imageview and then `setImageMatrix` that imageview everytime the onTouch event is called.

My current problem is the edittext is not moveable, it cant be drag-drop, resize and rotate.

This is my `oncreate`:

```
    text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt);
    text.setOnTouchListener(this);
    text.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    text.buildDrawingCache();

    ImageView img = new ImageView(this);
    img.setImageBitmap(text.getDrawingCache());
    img.setImageMatrix(mMatrix);
```

And this is my `onTouch` event :

```
    v.buildDrawingCache();

    ImageView img = new ImageView(this);
    img.setImageBitmap(v.getDrawingCache());
    img.setImageMatrix(mMatrix);
    img.setAlpha(mAlpha);
```

I think the problem is because i need to make a new instance of imageview instead of converting the edittext to imageview directly.

Please help me out, Thanks for your help.

Comment: what API level are you using?

Comment: so remove ImageView and use View.setScale*, View.setX/Y, View.setRotate*

Comment: @pskink Thanks, i will try your solution. Is it any other way to make this happen if my target API is < 11?